# Speed of Magento

Tags: php, magento

So I am thinking of implementing Magento in a site at work. But I am worried since it is a feature heavy, free-source application, it might run as slow as some Wordpress and Joomla sites I created in the past.

Is Magento a fast e-commerce platform? If not, does anybody have any suggestions for ready gui eCommerce solutions, that can be easily integrated into a custom website? Can be paid gui as long as they are not too off the wall expensive.

Comment: A question for either [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or [MageOverflow](https://magento.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The speed of Magento etc. is greatly affected by the server you're on. If you're on a shared server, it'll obviously be slow. If you're on a dedicated server and it's still slow, then something's fishy.

Comment: Magento runs as fast as the resources and physical server hardware you are willing to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Speed up your Magento store with the following admin settings:

1. Enable Cache: Just navigate to System > Cache Management and enable all cache types.
2. Reindex Data: Under System > Index Management select all indexes and hit the “Reindex Data” submit button.
3. Enable javaScript File merging: Navigate to System > Configuration > Developer > JavaScript Settings and select “Yes” under “Merge JavaScript Files”.
4. Combine CSS files: Go to System > Configuration > Developer > CSS settings and select “Yes” for “Merge CSS Files”.
5. Turn off the Logs: The settings are under System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings.
6. Enable the compilation: Go to System > Tools > Compilation and hit “Run Compilation Process”.

Hope, this will work !